# MaaS node with intel raid

Tags: maas

Anyone know how to enable MaaS to work with intel raid controllers? After commissioning it is showing up with 0 drives.

Deployment fails on this as well. [image: device info]

I am using: MAAS Version 1.8.0+bzr4001-0ubuntu2 (vivid1)

Comment: MaaS 1.9 seems could not detect Intel RAID1 as well. It detects all the drive but not the RAID volume. :D

Comment: I ended up doing a firmware and bios flash to the latest. And it works now. forgot to update this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing a firmware and bios flash to the latest. And it works now. forgot to update this